# How to invoke a Web Service which requires a certificate in Java?

Tags: java, web-services, security, ssl-certificate, x509

I need to communicate with a third party which has a .asmx web service. This web service is using https. I have the required certificate (.pfx).

I have added the certificate to the %JAVA_HOME% cacerts using keytool and now I want to invoke the service. And when I do that I get this error:

(403) Forbidden

So how can I tell my service to use the right certificate?